# Complex ID Assignment with conditions, iterative calculations, and tolerance matching

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a decently complex iterative matching function but I am drowning in ifelse and for functions that do not work. Unfortunately I don't have anyone to bounce ideas off so any support or thoughts are appreciated.

### My Data Structure

Each row of my data is an observation with many variables, pertinent ones are included in this example. The observation has an assigned `Sample_Name`, a `Matching_Group` corresponding to the sample name, measurements of `Time`, and a subjective `Assigned_idx` which is partially complete from earlier parts in the data cleaning. Each observed `Sample_Name` can contain 0-7 observations, but the `Matching_Group` will always contain 7 observations.

```
structure(list(Sample_Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS"), Matching_Group = c("QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS"), Time = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 7.203, 7.395, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.802, 1, 1.102, 1.2, 1.3, 1.398, 1.501, 1.6, 
7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8), Assigned_idx = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


Sample_Name Matching_Group  Time        Assigned_idx

A           QQ              1.000   
A           QQ              1.100   
A           QQ              1.200   
A           QQ              1.400   
A           QQ              1.600   
B           SS              7.203   
B           SS              7.395   
B           SS              7.500   
B           SS              7.600   
B           SS              7.700   
B           SS              7.802   
QQ          QQ              1.000       1
QQ          QQ              1.102       2
QQ          QQ              1.200       3
QQ          QQ              1.300       4
QQ          QQ              1.398       5
QQ          QQ              1.501       6
QQ          QQ              1.600       7
SS          SS              7.200       1
SS          SS              7.300       2
SS          SS              7.400       3
SS          SS              7.500       4
SS          SS              7.600       5
SS          SS              7.700       6
SS          SS              7.800       7
```

### My Problem

For each observation (row), I want to calculate a **ratio** of `Time` between *each* row of the corresponding `Matching_Group`. Each `Matching_Group` will have an assigned unique `Time_Ratio` value that the calculation needs to be equal to +/- some **tolerance**. If that calculated ratio **matches** the pre-defined ratio specific to the group, I want to **extract and assign** the `Assigned_idx` from the row belonging to the observations of the `Matching_Group` and assign it to the observation. If not, repeat calculation with the same observed `Time` and the `Time` in the next row of `Matching_Group`. Repeat until every observation has a value in `Assigned_idx`.

**Example:** In this data set, for both `Matching_Group` the `Time_Ratio` should be equal to `1.000 +/- 0.0020`. In my real data set, there will be unique `Time_Ratio` values per `Matching_Group` designated in a separate table. So for Row 3 with `Time` = `1.200`, the `Matching_Group` is `QQ`. When we calculate the ratio with the first `QQ` observed time, `1.200/1.000 = 1.200` which is outside of our defined tolerance --> next observed time of `QQ`. `1.200/1.102 = 1.089`...again outside of our tolerance. Finally though, `1.200/1.200 = 1.000` which indeed falls within our designated tolerance for this `Matching_Group`. In the row of the observation for `Matching_Group` that has the matching ratio, the `Assigned_idx` column holds `3`. We take this value, and map it into the `Assigned_idx` column for Row 3. Then repeat this for Row 4 and iterate the process.

*Desired outcome:*

```
Sample_Name Matching_Group  Time        Assigned_idx    Time_Ratio (Sample:Matching) 

A           QQ              1.000       1               1.0000
A           QQ              1.100       2               0.9982
A           QQ              1.200       3               1.0000
A           QQ              1.400       5               1.0014
A           QQ              1.600       7               1.0000
B           SS              7.203       1               1.0004
B           SS              7.395       3               0.9993
B           SS              7.500       4               1.0000
B           SS              7.600       5               1.0000
B           SS              7.700       6               1.0000
B           SS              7.802       7               1.0003
QQ          QQ              1.000       1               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.102       2               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.200       3               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.300       4               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.398       5               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.501       6               1.0000
QQ          QQ              1.600       7               1.0000
SS          SS              7.200       1               1.0000
SS          SS              7.300       2               1.0000
SS          SS              7.400       3               1.0000
SS          SS              7.500       4               1.0000
SS          SS              7.600       5               1.0000
SS          SS              7.700       6               1.0000
SS          SS              7.800       7               1.0000
```

I have tried approaching this using dplyr as I figured it should be able to handle what I am trying to accomplish (perhaps purrr is better suited?). Unfortunately I just can't seem to sequence my conditions and my expressions appropriately within ifelse and for functions. My attempts have included a mishmash of grouping %>% mutate with the ratio calculation, data.table::shift, etc. but I just can't seem to get it to work with my condition parameters. Also in case it is pertinent, in my real data there will be ~50 "Names" and ~25 matching groups. I will have a second data source listing the matching group names and respective ratio but did not include such detail in this example.

I'm honestly stumped, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: check out `case_when()` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: It would help if you can add examples or nomenclature from your data when you're describing your problem.  For example, is ratio a ratio between `Variable` values?  Does "observation group's name" refer to `Name`, and "another column that designates a different group to match with" refer to `Relative Group`?  Can you give an example of a ratio match failure and then "extract and assign" happening based on a subsequent row?  In general, providing example-based clarifications along the way will make it a lot easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @GordonShumway Thank you, I will read up on `case_when()` later today and see if I can make progress.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks for the helpful feedback, I have updated my post based on your comments and hopefully things are much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
First version was pretty clunky, here's a cleaner second pass:

```
library(tidyverse)
thresh <- .002
baseline <- 1.0
```

Still making `compare`, but now it's just two rows: one for each matching group, with `times` as a list of all the times per each `Matching_Group`:

```
compare <- df %>%
  filter(Sample_Name == Matching_Group) %>% 
  group_by(Matching_Group) %>%
  summarise(times = list(Time)) 

compare
  Matching_Group times    
  <chr>          <list>   
1 QQ             <dbl [7]>
2 SS             <dbl [7]>
```

Join `df` with `compare`, then use `purrr::map()` variants to get ratios, deltas (from baseline), and then the very handy [`detect_index()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/detect.html) can give us the first match of sub-threshold ratio.  (Note: This also solves the question from your comments about having `thresh` and `baseline` that are different for each matching group - we're still using static values here but the operations all assume those two variables are now columns in the df, which could in theory be different for each row or group.)

```
df %>%
  mutate(thresh = thresh,
         baseline = baseline) %>%
  inner_join(compare, by = "Matching_Group") %>%
  mutate(ratios = map2(Time, times, ~ .x / .y),
         deltas = map2(baseline, ratios, ~ abs(.x - .y)),
         Assigned_idx = map2_dbl(deltas, thresh, 
                                 ~detect_index(.x, ~ .x < .y, .y))) %>%
  select(-times, -ratios, -deltas)
```

Output:

```
   Sample_Name Matching_Group  Time Assigned_idx  thresh baseline
   <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 A           QQ              1.00           1. 0.00200       1.
 2 A           QQ              1.10           2. 0.00200       1.
 3 A           QQ              1.20           3. 0.00200       1.
 4 A           QQ              1.40           5. 0.00200       1.
 5 A           QQ              1.60           7. 0.00200       1.
 6 B           SS              7.20           1. 0.00200       1.
 7 B           SS              7.40           3. 0.00200       1.
 8 B           SS              7.50           4. 0.00200       1.
 9 B           SS              7.60           5. 0.00200       1.
10 B           SS              7.70           6. 0.00200       1.
# ... with 15 more rows
```

**Original solution**

Here's a `tidyverse` solution.  The idea is to swing out `Sample_Name` into wide form (that's `compare`), and then get the ratios for each row (and evaluate whether they pass the `thresh` test).  Then it's just a matter of recombining and cleaning up unnecessary variables.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

thresh <- .002
baseline <- 1.0
```

First, create `df` by adding `name2` to `data`.  It's just a copy of `Sample_Name` but with index values added:

```
df <- data %>%
  group_by(Sample_Name) %>%
  mutate(name2 = paste0(Sample_Name, 1:length(Sample_Name))) %>%
  ungroup() 

df
# A tibble: 25 x 5
   Sample_Name Matching_Group  Time Assigned_idx name2
   <chr>       <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>
 1 A           QQ              1.00           NA A1   
 2 A           QQ              1.10           NA A2   
 3 A           QQ              1.20           NA A3   
 4 A           QQ              1.40           NA A4   
 5 A           QQ              1.60           NA A5   
 6 B           SS              7.20           NA B1 
 ...
```

Now create the `compare` data frame:

```
compare <- df %>% 
      select(name2, Time) %>%
      spread(name2, value = Time)

compare
# A tibble: 1 x 25
     A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    B1    B2    B3    B4    B5    B6   QQ1   QQ2
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.  1.10  1.20  1.40  1.60  7.20  7.40  7.50  7.60  7.70  7.80    1.  1.10
# ... with 12 more variables: QQ3 <dbl>, QQ4 <dbl>, QQ5 <dbl>, QQ6 <dbl>,
#   QQ7 <dbl>, SS1 <dbl>, SS2 <dbl>, SS3 <dbl>, SS4 <dbl>, SS5 <dbl>,
#   SS6 <dbl>, SS7 <dbl>
```

Use `purrr:pmap` to compute ratios and compare against `thresh`:

```
matched_df <- df %>%
  pmap(~ compare %>% 
         select(starts_with(..2)) %>% 
         mutate_all(funs(..3/., which(abs(baseline - ./..3 ) < thresh)[1])) %>%
         select(contains("_"))
       ) %>% 
  bind_rows(.) 

matched_df
# A tibble: 25 x 28
   `QQ1_/` `QQ2_/` `QQ3_/` `QQ4_/` `QQ5_/` `QQ6_/` `QQ7_/` `QQ1_[` `QQ2_[`
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>   <int>
 1    1.00   0.907   0.833   0.769   0.715   0.666   0.625       1      NA
 2    1.10   0.998   0.917   0.846   0.787   0.733   0.688      NA       1
 3    1.20   1.09    1.00    0.923   0.858   0.799   0.750      NA      NA
 4    1.40   1.27    1.17    1.08    1.00    0.933   0.875      NA      NA
 5    1.60   1.45    1.33    1.23    1.14    1.07    1.00       NA      NA
```

Finally, bind `matched_df` to `df` and clean up.
The key operation that narrows down to just the correctly matched indexes is `filter(Assigned_idx == matched2)`.  Up until that point, all of the possible ratios for each `Sample_Name`-to-`Matching_Group` assignment are present.

```
bind_cols(df, matched_df) %>%
  select(-name2, -Assigned_idx) %>%
  gather(Assigned_idx, value, -contains("/"), -Sample_Name, -Matching_Group, -Time) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  gather(matched2, Time_Ratio, -Assigned_idx, -value, -Sample_Name, -Matching_Group, -Time) %>%
  mutate(Assigned_idx = str_replace(Assigned_idx, "_\\[", ""),
         matched2 = str_replace(matched2, "_/", "")) %>%
  filter(Assigned_idx == matched2) %>%
  arrange(Sample_Name) %>%
  select(-value, -matched2) %>%
  mutate(Assigned_idx = str_sub(Assigned_idx, -1),
         Time_Ratio = round(Time_Ratio, 4))

       Sample_Name Matching_Group  Time Assigned_idx Time_Ratio
1            A             QQ 1.000            1     1.0000
2            A             QQ 1.100            2     0.9982
3            A             QQ 1.200            3     1.0000
4            A             QQ 1.400            5     1.0014
5            A             QQ 1.600            7     1.0000
6            B             SS 7.203            1     1.0004
7            B             SS 7.395            3     0.9993
8            B             SS 7.500            4     1.0000
...
```

Not my prettiest solution...for all the `tidyverse` wizards out there, happy to learn from any suggestions.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Sample_Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS"), Matching_Group = c("QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS"), Time = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 7.203, 7.395, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.802, 1, 1.102, 1.2, 1.3, 1.398, 1.501, 1.6, 
7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8), Assigned_idx = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hey Andrew,  I was able to get the above working with my real data! Just wanted to ask a follow up question, please let me know if it would be best to create a new post entirely as this would involve modifying the original data frame I would have provided. I tried to play around with it but do you have any suggestions for how to incorporate `thresh` and `baseline` values that are characteristic for each `Matching_Group`? This would look like the original `data` but with two additional columns `thresh` & `baseline` which I already have `left_join`ed in (each row would be populated).

Comment: Also follow-up question #2, for the two `gather` steps, I have 10-12 extraneous metadata columns I want to keep. To keep these, I have to enter all of them into `gather(..., -metadata1, -metadata2, etc.)`. Any suggestions for how to do this without explicitly referencing each column? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi Bill, see updated solution.  The new version obviates your second question about `gather` in this instance, but in general, you can just add the variables you *do* want to gather, instead of listing all the ones you don't.  See the [gather docs](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) for examples.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your help. I introduced a few things to accommodate the more complex nature of my real data and I now have everything working great and **fast**. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/R

a = structure(list(Sample_Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS"), Matching_Group = c("QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "QQ", 
"QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "QQ", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS"), Time = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 7.203, 7.395, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.802, 1, 1.102, 1.2, 1.3, 1.398, 1.501, 1.6, 
7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8), Assigned_idx = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"));

tol = 0.002;

a$Time_Ratio <- NA;

for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  s_name <- a[i, "Sample_Name"];
  mg     <- a[i, "Matching_Group"];
  s_time <- a[i, "Time"];

  for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
    mg_name <- a[j, "Sample_Name"];
    if (mg_name == mg) {
      mg_time <- a[j, "Time"];
      time_ratio = s_time/mg_time;
      if (abs(time_ratio - 1.0) < tol) {
        a[i, "Assigned_idx"] <- a[j, "Assigned_idx"];
        a[i, "Time_Ratio"] <- time_ratio;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

print(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, works as intended for both the sample dataset and my real data!